# "Failed creating Java" when using Windows Services to start Cassandra

Tags: windows, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, apache-commons-daemon

I have had Cassandra 3.11.1 up and running correctly with no Java issues. I've been trying to set it up as a service using Apache Commons Daemon as recommended in the install guide. I was able to install it as a service, but when I attempt to start the service through Windows Services Manager it fails. The log reads:

```
Commons Daemon procrun (64-bit) started
Running 'cassandra' service...
Starting Service...
Failed creating Java
ServiceStart returned 1
Run Service finished.
```

Through cassandra config I am pointing to the 64 bit daemon prunsrv application.

Since cassandra seems to be working perfectly on its own it seems like it's a problem with prunsrv, but I have no idea how to track that down. I've seen similar problems, but it always seems to be a 32 vs 64 bit issue or the wrong environment paths for cassandra. Those seem fine for me.

Thank you!